# shapley values - error on dimensions of the data

Tags: dimensions, shap, shapley

I get the following error when running my code using shap for my CNN model: AssertionError: AssertionError:Instance must have 1 or 2 dimensions!` -  I would appreciate any advice

### Using 1484 background data samples could cause slower run times. Consider using shap.sample(data, K) or shap.kmeans(data, K) to summarize the background as K samples.

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_193211/2006523994.py in <cell line: 7>()
5 # Generate SHAP values for a random test image
6 # shape (sample, height, width, channels)
----> 7 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
8 shap.initjs()
9 # Plot the SHAP values for the test image

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shap/explainers/_kernel.py in shap_values(self, X, **kwargs)
154             X = X.tolil()
155         assert x_type.endswith(arr_type) or sp.sparse.isspmatrix_lil(X), "Unknown instance type: " + x_type
--> 156         assert len(X.shape) == 1 or len(X.shape) == 2, "Instance must have 1 or 2 dimensions!"
157
158         # single instance
*
AssertionError: Instance must have 1 or 2 dimensions!

My code:
import shap
# Define the SHAP explainer object
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(best_model, X_test)

```
# Generate SHAP values for a test image
# shape (nrsamples, height, width, channels)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.initjs()
# Plot the SHAP values for the test image
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

Dimensions of X_test:
X_test.shape
(1484, 74, 62, 119)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.